How to do rate limit for each website using Mod Security Module in Apache?
I have setup Mod Security (v2.9.5)  for Apache 2.4.52 version on Ubuntu 22.04.
I want to do 'Rate Limit' for each website using Mod Security Rule, It should ask client to Retry after 'n' time (seconds may be).
So my Apache server running 100+ websites, I need different rate limit for each website.
Like

domain1.com - 100 Requests/Minutes from same IP
domain2.com - 100 Requests/Minutes from same IP

I am trying to setup rule for that, but I think I need more expertise using mod security to build such rule.
# Rule 1: Initialize website-specific counter
SecAction "phase:1,id:900,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}/%{SERVER_NAME}/count/60"

# Rule 2: Increment website-specific counter and log full variable
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@rx ^([^:]+)" \
  "id:901,log,pass,setvar:ip.%{REMOTE_ADDR}/%{SERVER_NAME}/count/60+=1"
# Rule 3: Block if request count exceeds 100 per 60 seconds
SecRule IP:%{REMOTE_ADDR}/%{SERVER_NAME}/count/60 "@gt 1" \
    "id:902,phase:1,deny,status:429,\
    log,msg:'Client exceeded request limit for %{SERVER_NAME} from IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}, please try again later.'"

Can anyone please help me with this?

You may want to use something like Apache mod-evasive for this. It provides the required features you're looking for.

Yes , that is one of the option, but I already in need of mod_Security on my server as firewall , so I need to set it up using mod security so don't need to install separate module for rate limit only.
Hence I am looking for set up rate limit using mod security.

@RahulThakkar - have you solved this, I would love to hear what you did?
